# Publish my Pinterest to a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, pinterest

Is it impossible to publish to a page timeline instead of to my personal timeline? I have a FB page for my website and a pinterest for my website, and I would love to enable automatic sharing so it shows up in the FB timeline of the page.

The default configuring is publishing to a personal timeline and FB every time asks to change to my personal user account, when I want to add Pinterest to my Facebook from pinterest.com.

Answer (score 0):

According to this page:

http://pinnablebusiness.com/how-businesses-can-add-pinterest-to-their-facebook-page/

There is no way to natively add your pinterest feed to a facebook page that isn't your profile. It does however provide a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few if-this-then-that recipes (like [this one](https://ifttt.com/recipes/36187)) that purport to do that for you.

The ones I looked at seemed to simply take the RSS feed from a Pinterest board and use new items on that to post to a Facebook page. There's probably one there that can be modified to your liking.